# How can I uninstall adobe acroread?

Tags: pdf

I want to uninstall acroread that I downloaded from adobe's website and installed. How can I do that?

Comment: How did you install it? What guide did you follow?

Comment: @dadexix86 I installed it through the installer program from the adobe's website.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an UNINSTALL script in the same folder where you installed it.

```
$ locate UNINSTALL
/usr/local/Adobe/Reader9/bin/UNINSTALL

$ cd /usr/local/Adobe/Reader9/bin
$ sudo ./UNINSTALL
```

Done!

Comment: I also had to remove an icon of Adobe Reader from the list of applications in GNOME. The icon was in `~/.local/share/applications/`. It might also be in `/usr/share/applications/`

Comment: $ locate UNINSTALL returned nothing in my case.

Answer (score 27):

Or if that still doesn't work and returns `Package acroread is not installed, so not removed` you can try `sudo apt-get purge adobereader-enu && sudo apt-get autoremove`.

(Taken from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1453166#5)

Comment: My +1 for you ! :)

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This is it, because the package installed from .deb showed the package name adobereader-enu, not adobereader

Answer (score 6):

I also tried many ways to uninstall adobe reader 9 and this method worked for me

```
sudo apt-get purge acroread-bin
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: This seems to be the only viable solution on 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed it manually, then  you have can run

```
locate adobereader
```

Then remove it from there and delete the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Adobe Reader based on video here: https://youtu.be/04-J55bnTLQ
Then, I saw the software only allows me to see pdf files, but not to sign them; for uninstall Adobe Reader,it worked for me this:

```
sudo apt-get purge adobereader-enu && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Good. this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove acroread
```

or if you have Synaptic installed you can use that as well.

It should also show up in Software Center if your search for it, but I'm not well-versed in Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

> **sudo rm -Rf /opt/Adobe**

---

**Ubuntu 18.04**

Try this command, it worked for me.