# How do I uninstall Adobe Reader?

Tags: package-management, adobe

I have recently downloaded Adobe Reader for Linux from their website and run it using `dpkg -i .....`. I actually downloaded i386 version and my laptop is 64-bit. It then gave an error as:

> package management system damaged.

I searched on this website and fixed it using `sudo apt-get -f install`. Then the Adobe Reader got installed. But now I want to uninstall it.

I tried running:

```
sudo apt-get remove adobereader-enu
sudo apt-get autoremove adobereader-enu
```

But it was of no use.

I went to the home folder and removed *.adobe* folder (this was hidden). But still it didn't get uninstalled.

I manually tried to remove the *.config* files of adobe, even then it was not uninstalled.

How can I get rid it?

(This topic is similar to other threads, but I tried the methods given in those threads, but I couldn't uninstall the Reader).

Comment: Possible duplicate?

Comment: @Aditya that would be this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109445

Answer (score 14):

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge adobereader-enu
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```

Comment: When I try the first command, it says "E:unable to locate package adobereader-enu".

Comment: after adobe press tab to see which packages are installed

Comment: Nothing happens after pressing tab.

Comment: so it is removed completely, run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to remove it from Synaptics Package Manager.
Type "adobe reader" in the search; then right click "Mark for removal" then "Apply". Otherwise it should be easily located with Origin -> Local.
Best,