# Removing Adobe Acrobat (acroread) can still run?

Tags: uninstall, pdf, adobe, purge

I recently installed the Adobe Acrobat hoping it's like the Microsoft version but evince is still better if you ask me.

I have been trying to remove it using
`sudo apt-get purge acroread && sudo apt-get autoremove` which didn't work so I tried `sudo apt-get remove acroread` which also didnt work.

`whereis acroread` returns this

`acroread: /usr/bin/acroread /usr/bin/X11/acroread /usr/share/man/man1/acroread.1.gz`

I have been using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109445/how-can-i-uninstall-adobe-acroread?newreg=78c59830dc3e46bf9c623d7014142c3f) to try and remove it but did nothing. Adobe Acrobat stopped support for linux (http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/) so i followed [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-adobe-reader-ubuntu-14-10/) for installation.

Comment: Did you rebooted after removal?

Comment: What does `sudo dpkg -S /usr/bin/acroread` say? Btw, you could also try Okular, it's great too.

Comment: @GTRONICK i did reboot

Comment: @Hi-Angel this is what it said `acroread-bin: /usr/bin/acroread`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally you need to remove package `acroread-bin`, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get purge acroread-bin
```